# Scheduled Lambda to trigger from Aws Java Sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-java-sdk

I would like to [schedule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/RunLambdaSchedule.html) the trigger of Lambda from [Aws Java Sdk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/AmazonCloudWatchClient.html), the schedule could be more than a year from now, so SQS might not be an option. Is this possible?

I cannot find any example in the web and in their sdk documentation.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot schedule  the lambda directly. The first link you provided outlines what you need to do.

So the gist of it, is that you need to create a cloudwatch event and wire it up to trigger the lambda function when it fires. you should be able to do this by looking at the SDK documentation.

Comment: cloudwatch events PutRule method and lamda AddPermission method (you need to add the permission for the lambda function to get the event)